# How to parse json in Local using Flutter

Tags: flutter

This is my `json`:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Tata steel",
      "menu": [
        {
          "name": "LD1"
        },
        {
          "name": "LD2"
        },
        {
          "name": "LD3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Tata steel 1",
      "menu": [
        {
          "name": "LD1"
        },
        {
          "name": "LD2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I the error i got is something like this :
`Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'"`

**This is my Model Class**

```
class JsonModel {
  String name;
  Menu menu;

  JsonModel({this.name, this.menu});
  factory JsonModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return JsonModel(
        name: parsedJson['name'], menu: Menu.fromJson(parsedJson['menu']));
  }
}

class Menu {
  String nameMenu;
  Menu({
    this.nameMenu,
  });

  factory Menu.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Menu(nameMenu: json['name']);
  }
}
```

**used in Main.dart**

```
Future<String> _loadShapeAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/docs1/a.json');
}

Future loadShape() async {
  String jsonString = await _loadShapeAsset();
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
  print(jsonResponse);
  JsonModel shape = new JsonModel.fromJson(jsonResponse['data'][0]);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you get the error from when calling `json.decode`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following step:-

1) You can create below model:-

```
class ResponseModel {
  List<DataModel> dataList;

  ResponseModel({this.dataList});

  factory ResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    try {
      List<DataModel> menuList = new List();

      if (parsedJson.containsKey('data')) {
        var tempList = parsedJson['data'] as List;
        menuList = tempList.map((i) => DataModel.fromJson(i)).toList();
      }

      return ResponseModel(dataList: menuList);
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

class DataModel {
  String name;
  List<MenuModel> menuNameList;

  DataModel({this.name, this.menuNameList});

  factory DataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    try {
      List<MenuModel> menuList = new List();

      if (parsedJson.containsKey('menu')) {
        var tempList = parsedJson['menu'] as List;
        menuList = tempList.map((i) => MenuModel.fromJson(i)).toList();
      }

      return DataModel(name: parsedJson['name'], menuNameList: menuList);
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

class MenuModel {
  String menuName;

  MenuModel({this.menuName});

  factory MenuModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MenuModel(menuName: json['name']);
  }
}
```

2) Replace your model in method like below:-

```
Future loadShape() async {
    String jsonString = await _loadShapeAsset();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);print(jsonResponse);
    ResponseModel shape = new ResponseModel.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    print('====NAME======${shape.dataList[0].name}');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this model class,

```
class JsonModel {
  String name;
  List<Menu> menu = [];

  JsonModel({this.name, this.menu});

  factory JsonModel.fromJson(Map parsedJson) {
    List<Menu> tempMenuList = [];
    parsedJson['menu'].forEach((menuItem){
      tempMenuList.add(Menu.fromJson(menuItem));
    });
    return JsonModel(
        name: parsedJson['name'], menu: tempMenuList);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this model class

```
import 'dart:convert';

Categoriesphoto categoriesphotoFromJson(String str) => Categoriesphoto.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String categoriesphotoToJson(Categoriesphoto data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Categoriesphoto {
    List<Datum> data;

    Categoriesphoto({
        this.data,
    });

    factory Categoriesphoto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Categoriesphoto(
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Datum {
    String name;
    List<Menu> menu;

    Datum({
        this.name,
        this.menu,
    });

    factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        name: json["name"],
        menu: List<Menu>.from(json["menu"].map((x) => Menu.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "menu": List<dynamic>.from(menu.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Menu {
    String name;

    Menu({
        this.name,
    });

    factory Menu.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Menu(
        name: json["name"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
    };
}
```